# Facebook Graph API - Two level app permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a facebook app which initially will consist of a facebook login button. I want two roles for the same app:

1. Admin
2. User

Admin will need to have `manage_pages` and `user_posts` permissions. 
User will need to have only `user_posts` permission.

Is that possible to have same FB login button but with different permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Users can change the permissions they want to allow in the login process, and you can check which ones they accepted after the process. If you want to specifically separate Admins and regular Users, you have to change the scope parameter before the user hits the button.